# How to query AWS to get ELB names and attached instances to that using python boto3 modules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-elb

I cant find code with boto3. I'm able to get elb name and InstanceID separately but cant link them together to find attached instances to ELB names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my solution which I got it to work. Thank you John.

```
elbList = boto3.client('elb')
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

bals = elbList.describe_load_balancers()
for elb in bals['LoadBalancerDescriptions']:
    print 'ELB DNS Name : ' + elb['DNSName']
    for ec2Id in elb['Instances']:
        running_instances = \
            ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name'
                                 , 'Values': ['running']},
                                 {'Name': 'instance-id',
                                 'Values': [ec2Id['InstanceId']]}])
        for instance in running_instances:
            print("              Instance : " + instance.public_dns_name);
```

Answer (score 11):

**Classic Load Balancer**

The boto3 [`describe_load_balancers()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elb.html#ElasticLoadBalancing.Client.describe_load_balancers) functions returns a list of instances:

```
{
    'LoadBalancerDescriptions': [
        {
            'LoadBalancerName': 'string',
            'DNSName': 'string',
            ....
            'Instances': [
                {
                    'InstanceId': 'string'
                },
            ],
            ....
        },
    ],
    'NextMarker': 'string'
}
```

The `Instances` section returns the IDs of the instances for the load balancer.

**Application Load Balancer (ELBv2)**

This one is harder. The Application Load Balancer has multiple **Target Groups**. Ports on instances are registered to a Target Group.

The only command that seems to list instances in a Target Group is [`describe_target_health()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.describe_target_health), which returns the **instance** and **port** (because one instance can serve multiple targets):

```
{
    'TargetHealthDescriptions': [
        {
            'Target': {
                'Id': 'i-0f76fade',
                'Port': 80,
            },
            'TargetHealth': {
                'Description': 'Given target group is not configured to receive traffic from ELB',
                'Reason': 'Target.NotInUse',
                'State': 'unused',
            },
        },
        {
            'HealthCheckPort': '80',
            'Target': {
                'Id': 'i-0f76fade',
                'Port': 80,
            },
            'TargetHealth': {
                'State': 'healthy',
            },
        },
    ],
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        '...': '...',
    },
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sam, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple script to find the list of instance attached to an ELB, as an input you may have to provide the ELB name

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import boto3
import sys
import string


elb_name = raw_input("What is ELB name? :: ")

print ("\n")
print ("THE LIST OF INSTANCES ATTACHED TO THIS ELB IS \n")
elbList = boto3.client('elb')
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

bals = elbList.describe_load_balancers()
for elb in bals['LoadBalancerDescriptions']:

    set2 = elb['LoadBalancerName']
    if elb_name == set2 :
        inst =  elb['Instances']
        ct = sys.getrefcount(inst)
        count = ct
        for x in range(count):
            iv = elb['Instances'][x]
            id = str(iv.values())
            id = string.replace(id, "'", "")
            print id.strip('[]')
```